# Can I replace regular DIMMs with (non-ECC) RDIMM RAM?

Tags: memory, compatibility

We have a bunch of leftover RDIMM modules, and I have a machine that could do with a memory upgrade, but it's a regular old Intel i5 which is currently using regular old DIMMs.

I wouldn't be mixing them but replacing the existing (non-registered) DIMMs -- but I haven't found anything that tells me if the RDIMMs will work.

In terms of other specifications (DDR3 1866, they're actually slightly overspecced (CPU takes up to DDR3 1600), but I don't think that could be a problem.

**Edit:**
I'm hoping for a general answer but in case that matters: I have an Ivy-Bridge i5 on an Intel DQ77CP mainboard. Intel's database says for both the CPU and the board that ECC is not supported but has nothing about registered RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the motherboard specifications.

> Usually, the motherboard must match the memory type; as a result,
>   registered memory will not work in a motherboard not designed for it,
>   and vice versa. Some PC motherboards accept or require registered
>   memory, but registered and unregistered memory modules cannot be
>   mixed.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory)

If you can't find any info about it I think you can just try it. The worst thing that can happen is that your PC won't boot.

**Edit:** The specifications of that Intel board says this about supported RAM modules:

> Unbuffered, single-sided, or double-sided DIMMs with the 
>   following restriction: Does not support double-sided x16 
>   DIMMs

[System Memory for Intel Desktop Board DQ77CP](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000007840/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html)

**Edit 2:** Unbuffered is synonymous with unregistered.

Comment: Is "unbuffered" the same as "non-registered"? And does support for unbuffered mean that buffered (if that is the same thing...) automatically won't work, or does it only mean that the board can't make use of the feature?

Comment: Yes it is the same. Read the wiki article I linked. It starts with "Registered (also called buffered) memory..." :) And if it's not supported then it won't work.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. Also thanks for finding a more detailed set of informations on the board. I had only found this before: https://ark.intel.com/products/59045/Intel-Desktop-Board-DQ77CP -- which doesn't mention registered RAM

Comment: I found the compatibility info on the same site. Click on the Product Support on the bottom and there is a link called Compatibility to get all the details.